# How to load a placeholder image then toggle to the real one once HTTP calls are done?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently working on a project with a particularly large gif file on the page.

I'd like to be able to load something much smaller, like a static image or perhaps even just a colored div, while the gif is loading to improve the performance of the website.

The current tech stack is Nuxt and SASS.

Apparently I need to add some example code. Here is how the image is rendered at the moment.

Also, to add some further clarity, I am looking to prioritize the loading of all other elements on the page before this gif.

```html
<img src="filename.gif" />
```

Comment: It's expected on Stack Overflow that you provide some example code, no matter how simple

Comment: @Zach Jensz - done

Comment: @PeterB React was not mentioned in the question

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm using Nuxt/Vue, not React

Comment: Adding some relevant piece of code is indeed heavily recommended, especially when asking a `how-to` question (forbidden here and worth a `close` vote). Do you want to load the GIF after everything or get something progressive? Like a page with a blurry GIF and then a more HD one. As in here for example: https://using-gatsby-image.gatsbyjs.org/blur-up/ Also, is using Cloudinary a possibility?

Comment: There are other elements on the page that should take priority over the gif, so I'm looking to load the gif last. I'd be happy for that to either be a blurry static image, or just a coloured div.

Can't use Cloudinary I'm afraid

Comment: What kind of elements (DOM, HTTP calls)? Some code would be welcome here, to show us what you've tried so far. Is there any logic regarding the order of the load (specific event/state need to be completed before the GIF) or is it just performance-wise (getting it loaded at last in the flame chart)? Where is the GIF? Is it in the viewport originally? So, is a toggle fine regarding the loading of the GIF or does it need to be there initially (in a smaller resolution)?

Comment: You're using `fetch()` or `asyncData()` hooks? Is it a local or remote image?

Comment: It's a local image. The page does use the fetch hook to retrieve different data for the page, the site is statically generated though so this will all be done at build time.

Comment: None of my questions were answered regarding my previous comment (`What kind of...`), so I gave a simple answer based on what was provided by the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have a big local image `tasty.jpg` (huge 4k pizza) and a small one with ducks, here is how to make a simple swap between both while using the `fetch()` hook.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img
      :src="require(`~/assets/img/${currentImage}`)"
      width="800"
      height="800"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    await this.$axios.$get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    console.log('5000 photos loaded!')
  },
  fetchOnServer: false, // the `fetch` hook will be called only client-side
  computed: {
    currentImage() {
      if (process.server) return 'duck.jpg'
      return this.$fetchState.pending ? 'duck.jpg' : 'tasty.jpg'
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<style>
   .wrapper {
     width: 30rem;
     height: 30rem;
     background-color: orangered;
   }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
   <img src="filename.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: Will this force everything else on the page to load before the gif though? That's what I'm looking to do

Comment: it will load when its turn and yes it will load before the gif

Comment: This will not have any prio, the GIF will be loaded as is while checking the DOM. At least, with the given code.