# Nuxt 'Undefined Image' - Dynamic images

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I cannot get dynamic images to load using webpack and nuxt.js

My data is displaying correctly, however I cannot use "`require`" on any of my dynamic images without the page displaying `Cannot find module './undefined.svg'`

`{{server.image}}` - the string displays correctly on the browser and on refresh however when I put the property into an image I get `Cannot find module './undefined.svg'`.

I've tried the following fix but this still does not work.

**HTML**

```html
<img class="image" :src="imageSource" :alt="picture">
```

**Computed property**

```js
computed: {
  imageSource() {
    return require(`~/assets/images/${this.server.image}.svg`)
  }
}
```

**Result**

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './undefined.svg'"

Comment: Should be working fine. You probably have some async things happening on your `server.image` state? Could you give us more details on that one?

Comment: Thanks again...yes Async going on. I'll have to put a placeholder image in it's place

Comment: You can give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72214412/8816585